# R, create a new sorted dataframe with use of dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

i am new to R and a bit overwhelmed by an assignment. i am asked to create a new dataframe out of an existing one ( the `diamonds` data that come preinstalled with `ggplot2`). The dataframe should look as follows:

```
mean_price median_price min_price max_price n
```

All sorted by `clarity` where `n` is the number of entries in that clarity category.

- I know i can access the clarity with `diamonds$clarity`
- and i know i can get mean, median etc... with `mean(diamonds$price)`
  etc..

But how do i sort it according to clarity and put it into a new dataframe ?

Comment: I can't find the diamonds dataset. `data(diamonds)`
##Warning message:
In data(diamonds) : data set ‘diamonds’ not found`  Perhaps`diamonds[order(diamonds$clarity),]` or using `dplyr`, `arrange(diamonds, clarity)`

Comment: You should have mentioned that the diamonds is from library(ggplot2)

Comment: Just shows what a noobie i am ...  i am sorry for forgetting that

Comment: the dataframe needs to include the mean etc.. of all the data.. but sorted by clarity.. So mean of the price when clarity is a, b , c etc...

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected result as using `group_by` it is already sorting by 'clarity'

Comment: I suggest you read the following , it wasn't easy to understand your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

  diamonds %>%
      group_by(clarity) %>%

      summarise(mean_price = mean(price) ,  min_price =min(price) ,max_price = max(price) ,
      median_price = median(as.numeric(price)),  count = n()) %>%

      arrange(clarity)
```

for arranging in descending order use `arrange(desc(clarity))` instead of `arrange(clarity)`

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in using `arrange` here, Just check the output with and without it.  The `group_by` already sorts it by clarity

Comment: yeah you're right , any way I don't know whether he is going to arrange it in ascending or descending order , he will need the `arrange` if he wants to arrange it in descending order

Comment: Hmm i tried to copy it and assign it to a variable... just nothing happened :( what am i missing :(